# Нужно привести в соответствие страницу справки об общих (вики) сообщениях

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка, общие-сообщения

Текущая ревизия [страницы справки об общих сообщениях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) содержит устаревшую информацию. В частности правило по преобразованию сообщения в общее на основании кол-ва правок отменено как минимум [с апреля 2014 года](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/11741/40).

> [image: хлам]

Картинку в том числе тоже стоит русифицировать. Может быть есть и другие моменты.

Для сравнения, [ссылка на одноимённую страницу на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).