# Переписываем страницу справки про общие сообщения!

Tags: дефект, справка, общие-сообщения

Так как справка давно не обновлялась, на мете [идёт сбор всех дефектов справки в одном месте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12602/). Некоторые страницы справки устарели и нуждаются в серьёзной корректировке. Одна из таких статьей справки — статья [Общие сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).

Здесь я предлагаю переписать эту страницу справки, чтобы потом сотруднику осталось лишь скопировать её.

Какая информация конкретно устарела:

- [Устарели некоторые пункты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8506/532877):

> В этих случаях, мы верим, что сообщение де-факто является общим:
>
> - тело сообщение было отредактировано минимум 5 различными участниками;
> - сообщение было отредактировано 10 раз автором;

А раз в списке остался ещё 1 пункт, то его надо переделать в предложение.

- [Нужно заменить скриншот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8865/532877).
- Есть мелкие дефекты:

  - Нет закрывающей кавычки:

  > Чтобы опубликовать общий ответ, вам необходимо отметить его общим», за счет выставления галки справа под телом ответа.

  - Проблемы с [ё](/questions/tagged/%d1%91).
  - Неподходящий заголовок у абзаца, про то, как сообщение может стать общим.

  > #### Как работают общие сообщения?

  Его надо заменить на этот:

  > #### Как сообщение может стать общим?

  - Здесь написанное в скобках лучше написать нормальным предложением, а не через запятую, ибо не звучит:

  > ...статус не может быть отменен (за исключением экстремальных случаев, вручную модератором).

  - Есть другие дефекты (в основном связанные с пунктуацией или несогласованиями).

**P.S:** Так как ответ на этот пост будет сделан общим (судьба иронична), то для того, чтобы его отредактировать, нужно всего 100 баллов репутации. Пожалуйста, помогите улучшить новую версию статьи!

Answer (score 2):

## Общие сообщения

#### Что такое общие сообщения?

Общие сообщения предназначены для совместного редактирования всеми участниками и не приносят баллов репутации.

#### В каких случаях мне следует отмечать мой ответ общим?

- Когда вы хотите подчеркнуть принадлежность сообществу вашего ответа, таким образом чтобы он постоянно оставался источником качественной информацией за счёт постоянного улучшения правками.
- Когда вы считаете, что ваш ответ может быть более полезен, если получит не только голоса, но и улучшающие правки участников сообщества.

#### Как сообщение может стать общим?

- По желанию автора сообщения. Чтобы опубликовать общий ответ, установите галочку у пункта «общий» справа под телом ответа:

[image]

- Автоматически. Если вы отвечаете на общий вопрос, то система сделает ваш ответ «общим».
- По решению модераторов. Если модераторы находят сообщение общим, они могут вручную изменить его статус. Если сообщение получило статус общего одним из выше указанных способов, статус может отменить только модератор.

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на публикацию [Что такое «общие» сообщения?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2436/532877).

Comment: Лишняя запятая: "«общим», с помощью".

Comment: @Глеб переформулировал предложение и там уже лишней запятой нет :)